# Perl Error: X-Died: Missing newline after chunk data:

Tags: perl, http, get, lwp, lwp-useragent

While trying to get a webpage using LWP::UserAgent I am getting the following error

`X-Died: Missing newline after chunk data: 'OeXk0Yk1iRVhX.<Lot of this>...pOnR5cGU9InhzOnN' at /usr/share/perl5/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 481.`

To make things worse, it doesn't show up all the time.I am able to 'Get' the web page properly many times. Could someone shed some light on the issue ? Is it a bug in the Perl Module ? Is there a work around for this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is the cause of a bug likely from your version of `Net::HTTP`. There have been similar cases of this in the past. Download the newest version of this from CPAN or download the patch to fix this.

- [Net::HTTP chunked decoding bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=74431)
- [Net::HTTP chunk handling broken for non-blocking sockets](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=80670)

This bug could also be related to [LWP::UserAgent cuts chunked response sent through HTTPS](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=768394)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it would help your particular script, but maybe try wrapping your LWP get with the 
`eval { my $lwpget = get($url) }` operator.

And then perhaps evaluate the $scalar afterwards with

`if ($lwpget) { subroutine_do_something($lwpget); }`